# No instance for MonadState

Tags: haskell

I'm getting "No instance for MonadState BTState BT" and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've tried adding constraints in various places, putting MonadState in the deriving() clause, etc.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import System.Random
import Control.Monad.Error
import Control.Monad.State

-- I want to make a class of monads which contain random generator state.
class Monad m => RandMonad m where
  putGen :: StdGen -> m ()
  getGen :: m StdGen

-- the following creates a monadic type BT
data BTState = BTState
 { bGoalN :: Int
 , bRandState :: StdGen }

newtype BT a = BT { insideBT :: ErrorT String (State BTState) a }
    deriving(Monad)

runBT a s = runState (runErrorT $ insideBT a) s

instance RandMonad BT where
  getGen = BT $ gets bRandState
  putGen g = BT $ do { s <- get; put s {bRandState=g} }

-- trying to use BT
backtrackBT :: BT Int
backtrackBT = do
  s <- get
  put s {bGoalN=2}
  return 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to derive `MonadState`:

```
newtype BT a = ...
    deriving (Monad, MonadState BTState, MonadError String)
```

And `MonadError` while we're at it.

---

If you had tried just putting `deriving (Monad, MonadState, MonadError)`, you would have gotten a compiler error because you have to have an associated state or error type with your transformer stack, otherwise you'd be able to change the type of the error or the type of the state midway through the computation, which wouldn't typecheck elsewhere.